# Dynamic Biased Randomized Selection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, random, selection

I'm looking to implement an algorithm that picks items from a list randomly, albeit in a biased way. Say I have a value *priority* for each element in that list. I would like an element with higher priority appear more often in the selection.

Another thing is that the priority of these elements would be changed. If someone particularly picks an element rather than letting that element come from a random selection, the priority of that element should be increased by a certain factor.

I'm afraid I'm not quite sure how to phrase my question mathematically. Also, I don't know where to begin either. I found an article [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=22091) which deals with the first part but doesn't deal with dynamically increasing the priority of elements.

One approach I thought of is that more the priority of an element, the more copies we make of it. However, this is very unfeasible to implement in computer code

I've also posted this question on math.stackexchange hoping for some mathematical insight.

NOTE: Just to be clear, I'm not looking for any implementation of sort. I'm just looking for a clear direction/few insights so I can go ahead and code up my own algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible ways I can think of right now is,

Suppose there are two arrays, priority[k] and values[k]

```
priority[]={2,1,5,7}
values[]={"apple","banana","oranges","lollipop"}
```

To get a random value in a biased way:
 1. Let the sum of the priority array be S. In this example S=15.
2. Have a cumulative array of priority array,

```
`cumulative[]= {2,3,8,15}
```

3. Now generate a random number r <=S. Suppose it is 7
4. 7 is <8, the third element in cumulative array. So you return "orange"
If r=3, return "banana", if r=10, return "lollipop".

If someone particularly chooses an element simply increase the priority value of that element by a factor k.

Suppose k=2, and someone chooses oranges, the new arrays are

```
priority[]={2,1,7,7}
values[]={"apple","banana","oranges","lollipop"}
cumulative={2,3,10,17}
```

Using the same algorithm as described above you will get the desired results.

Comment: As a slight speedup, after generating your random number r, you can find the corresponding array position using binary search (since the list of partial sums is nondecreasing).